# How to disable output of QProcess

Tags: c++, qt, qprocess

I want to execute an external program in Qt and just get the return code. I do not want to see any ouput in the terminal whatsoever. I tried to redirect stderr and stdout to a file but the output of the command is still being printed on screen.

```
bool checkHostAlive(const QString& host, bool surpressOutput) {
    QStringList parameters;
#if defined(WIN32)
    parameters << "-n" << "1";
#else
    parameters << "-c 1";
#endif

    parameters << host;

    auto proc = QProcess();

    if(surpressOutput) {
        // Surpress ping output
        auto fileStdOut = QString();
        auto fileStdErr = QString();
        proc.setStandardErrorFile(fileStdErr);
        proc.setStandardOutputFile(fileStdOut);
    }

    if (proc.execute("ping", parameters) == 0) {
        return true;
    }

    return false; 
}
```

Comment: [`QProcess::execute`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qprocess.html#execute) is a `static` member so any state associated with the instance `proc` is irrelevant.  Also, the parameter passed to `setStandardErrorFile` et al. is supposed to be a valid file path: I'm not sure what an empty `QString` would actually do here.

Comment: @G.M. Thanks for pointing those out. I thought `.func`  is different than `::func`

Answer (score 0):

See e.g. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#setStandardErrorFile , which suggests `nullDevice()` as special value; alternately, look into https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#ProcessChannelMode-enum -- the default is `SeparateChannels`, which should send output to the calling program.

(Note that the `"-c 1"` for non-Windows is *probably* wrong; either `-c1` or two separate elements in the stringlist)

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
this->gotDoxygen=QProcess::execute("sh",QStringList()<<"-c"<<"which doxygen 2>&1 >/dev/null");
```

To check for the presence of the external doxygen app, doesn't show any output.